# Are there any other MIPS instruction that uses Memread in a single cycle control unit

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I was studying the single cycle datapath with control unit along with truth tables for mips instructions. I noticed that MemRead is only used by lw, by that I mean MemRead is only 1/true for lw. Are there any other instructions (including extended like addi) that uses MemRead?

here is an image for single cycle for convenience.
https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F79c%2F79c99e27-4e47-4bbe-b934-a7c7b67cd9dd%2FphpQu8UyV.png

Comment: I'd expect `lb`, `lbu`, `lh` (narrow loads) to use it, and also the unaligned load helpers `lwl` and `lwr` (left/right).

Comment: I see. So intuitively, the loads use memread. Where can I find truth tables for those instructions? Been scouring the net for a more comprehensive list of instruction truth table in a control unit.